# Get maximum number of framebuffer color attachments?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

I'm developing an OpenGL application and I need to find how many framebuffer color attachments are supported.  Is there a way to query OpenGL for that value?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two values that can potentially limit how many attachments you can use:

- `GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS` specifies how many color attachment points an FBO has. In other words, it correspond to the maximum value `n` you can use when specifying attachment points with `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTn`. This will limit how many color textures/renderbuffers can be attached to the FBO concurrently. You can get this limit with:

  ```
  GLint maxAttach = 0;
  glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS, &maxAttach);
  ```
- `GL_MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS` specifies how many buffers you can draw to at the same time. It is the maximum number of buffers you're allowed to pass to `glDrawBuffers()`, and also the maximum number of outputs allowed in fragment shaders. You can get this limit with:

  ```
  GLint maxDrawBuf = 0;
  glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS, &maxDrawBuf);
  ```

These two values do not have to be the same. So it is possible that you can have a certain number of attachments, but you can't draw to all of them at the same time.

The minimum value for both these limits is 8 in OpenGL 3.x and higher, up to and including the current 4.5 spec.

Answer (score 5):

You can get it by querying

```
int maxColorAttachments;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS, &maxColorAttachments);
```